# Does python multivariable assignment order mattering?

Tags: python, variables, linked-list, variable-assignment, singly-linked-list

I am working on leetcode problem 206 and have come up with :

```
class Solution(object):
    def reverseList(self, head):
        """
        :type head: ListNode
        :rtype: ListNode
        """
        
        if head:    
            if head.next:

                curr1 = head
                curr2 = head.next
                curr1.next = None

                while curr2:
                
                    #curr1, curr2.next, curr2 = curr2, curr1, curr2.next
                    #curr2.next, curr2, curr1 = curr1, curr2.next, curr2

                    curr1, curr2, curr2.next = curr2, curr2.next, curr1
                    
                return curr1
            
        return head
```

the code above works in the case of either commented out line but fails due to time for the currently un-commented line in the while loop.

Could anyone explain why this is?

I tried changing the order of the variables that must be changed and that somehow results in a differnet output. Even though the variables are swapping to the same other variables just in a different position.

Comment: yesk the order matters. first, the right hand side is evalutated (it is tuple) from left to right. Then assignments happen from left to right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the order matters. We can rewrite each of these tuple assignments as separate assignments to clarify this:

This working one:

```
curr1, curr2.next, curr2 = curr2, curr1, curr2.next
```

...is equivalent to (ignoring there is a `temp` name here):

```
temp = (curr2, curr1, curr2.next)
curr1 = temp[0]
curr2.next = temp[1]
curr2 = temp[2]
```

Let's do this breakdown with the non-working assignment:

```
curr1, curr2, curr2.next = curr2, curr2.next, curr1
```

This can be understood as:

```
temp = (curr2, curr2.next, curr1)
curr1 = temp[0]
curr2 = temp[1]
curr2.next = temp[2]
```

Note how the assignment to `curr2` impacts what the last assignment will be to. And in this case that is *not* what you want. You want the "old" `curr2` to get its `next` attribute updated, not the "new" one as is happening here. The assignment to `curr2` should happen *after* `curr.next` has been updated, and that is the case in the two working versions you provided.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but :  if  e = [1, 2, 3]
and i run :
e[0], e[2] = e[2], e[0]

print(e) I get [3, 2, 1] hwo does that make sense?

Comment: Again, split it up in the same way: `temp = (e[2], e[0]); e[0] = temp[0]; e[2] = temp[1]`

Answer (score 0):

The different "swaps" are changing the flow of the code. You'll see that if you use a debugger

You could do this:

```
class Solution:
    def reverseList(self, head):
        if not head or not head.next:
            return head
        first = ListNode(head.val)
        last = head.next
        while last:
            first = ListNode(last.val, first) 
            last = last.next
        return first
```